# Equation for bezier curve

Tags: linear-algebra, bezier-curve

I have a cubic bezier curve ; whose **1st anchor-point** is (a,b) **1st control-point** is (c,d) , **2nd control point** is (e,f) and **2nd anchor-point** is ( g,h );

Now I want an equation in **x** and **y** format; so that with the value of **x** I can calculate the **y** value of a point on the curve..

How to do this? How the equation will be?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: @J.M. that question have 6 answer ; but no one is accepted , so which one to take? if I take the 1st answer then there is u0, u1, u2, u3; what are those constants?

Comment: To summarize: there is an explicit form, but it is very unlikely that you'll be able to solve for $y$ as a function of $x$. If you can, use Hermite interpolation instead.